# Command not found: adb when executed from adb's directory

Tags: android, adb, android-sdk-tools

I just installed android studio and and platform tools and I cant call `adb` even though its clearly located in the same directory. I get this error:

```
zsh: command not found: adb
```

I'm new to the android SDK so this probably an easy fix. Any ideas?

Example execution:

```
agconti-Inspiron-5520 :: android-studio/sdk/platform-tools » adb            1 ↵
zsh: command not found: adb
agconti-Inspiron-5520 :: android-studio/sdk/platform-tools » ll           127 ↵
total 3.2M
-rwxrwx--- 1 agconti agconti 1.3M Jun 21 21:09 adb
drwxrwx--- 2 agconti agconti 4.0K Jun 21 21:12 api
-rwxrwx--- 1 agconti agconti  47K Jun 21 21:09 dmtracedump
-rwxrwx--- 1 agconti agconti 220K Jun 21 21:09 etc1tool
-rwxrwx--- 1 agconti agconti 197K Jun 21 21:09 fastboot
-rwxrwx--- 1 agconti agconti 9.9K Jun 21 21:09 hprof-conv
-rw-rw---- 1 agconti agconti 704K Jun 21 21:12 NOTICE.txt
-rw-rw---- 1 agconti agconti   39 Jun 21 21:09 source.properties
-rwxrwx--- 1 agconti agconti 754K Jun 21 21:09 sqlite3
drwxrwx--- 2 agconti agconti 4.0K Jun 21 21:09 systrace
```

Comment: can the down voter please explain what they are upset about?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Use:

```
./adb
```

Unless `.` is in your path it won't be found.  And for security, `.` shouldn't be in your path.

Comment: You're giving it a full path to the executable.  '.' means current directory.

Comment: but why does it require a `./` instead of just `adb`?

Comment: Because unix doesn't look in the current directory by default.  It looks in all the directories int he variable $PATH.  . is not in $PATH by default because its insecure-  if it was and I wrote an app called su and put it in my folder, I could trick an admin into using it instead of the real su and steal his password.  So since the current directory is not in PATH by default, you have to specify the directory to use apps in the current directory.  You can also just add "android-studio/sdk/platform-tools" to your path.